# PowerAutomate Azure Devops field updated notification

Tags: azure-devops, power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector, power-automate-desktop

I am able to use power automate and trigger azure devops work item change, work item created options. But I am trying to find if there is a way to retrieve particular work item field, custom field changes and what values are updated. For example, if target  work item date is changed from x to y, I want to sent a notification that value is updated from x to y. Will power automate support the functionality? Any suggestion or pointer would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check which values have changed via the Updates method of the DevOps REST API, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/updates/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP

I have shared an example of that approach in this thread: [Power Automate - How to create Azure DevOps work items only once when the trigger is a work item update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73976470/power-automate-how-to-create-azure-devops-work-items-only-once-when-the-trigge/73991535#73991535)

Comment: for example if I want check only if the title was changed or not then what would be my action in the settings?